# Generate regular expression to match SQL Server select statement

Tags: .net, regex

I need to make a regular expression to match `select` query syntax of SQL Server. Below is the query structure taken from msdn:

```
[ WITH { [ XMLNAMESPACES ,] [ <common_table_expression> [,...n] ] } ]  
    <query_expression>   
    [ ORDER BY { order_by_expression | column_position [ ASC | DESC ] }   
  [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ <FOR Clause>]   
    [ OPTION ( <query_hint> [ ,...n ] ) ]   
<query_expression> ::=   
    { <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) }   
    [  { UNION [ ALL ] | EXCEPT | INTERSECT }  
        <query_specification> | ( <query_expression> ) [...n ] ]   
<query_specification> ::=   
SELECT [ ALL | DISTINCT ]   
    [TOP ( expression ) [PERCENT] [ WITH TIES ] ]   
    < select_list >   
    [ INTO new_table ]   
    [ FROM { <table_source> } [ ,...n ] ]   
    [ WHERE <search_condition> ]   
    [ <GROUP BY> ]   
    [ HAVING < search_condition > ]
```

I need to make a regex which can match any select query written using above syntax.

I have created below regex, but it is not up to the mark. After where clause it is matching everything. https://regexr.com/3kp3g

Please help

Comment: You marked the question with .net tag, but the regex engine you are testing with only supports JS regex syntax. Where are you using the regex?

Comment: Regex is a poor choice for this.  You really need a parser.

Comment: A regular expression can't match arbitrary SQL expressions. As Tim said you need a parser.

Comment: Okay.. so any suggestion for parser that i can use for the same ?